# pygmentize Not Found error while installing phabricator

Tags: phabricator, pygments

I am not able to find a solution to this error ..googling didn't help as it returned some github links

[image]

can anyone help as there are not many post explaining this issue

Comment: Do you need advanced syntax highlighting? What OS are you using? Did you install pygmentize on the OS level? What does `which pygmentize` say?

Comment: @mnagel actually i did not install pygmentize....only enabled it in phabricator after posting on SO i read the error again with a clear mind  and was finally able to figure it out

Comment: So what was the solution?